# find range of value in matlab from two columns which are dependent

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file which contains 4 columns. First column is time based on seconds and the other three are my function. How is it possible to find a time for specific value in the time column? let me give an example:

let say I want to find where is this value in the second column: 0.7636 located in time column? I found it manually which is located between 6960-7020[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1-6LJIPxM_3c0pEQmh6YmhUTms/view?usp=sharing).

So, if I have for example a couple of values, and also considering different functions then it is difficult to do it manually.

I hope to hear your support. 
Thanks Sepideh

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about what a good solution is first. Let's call your three functions `f1(t)`, `f2(t)` and `f3(t)`. Now you have values `v=[v1,v2,v3]` and you want to know the best matching time value.

What is the best matching time value? You have to find some kind of distance metric, which tells you how close the data matches. As a default, I would use the 2-norm unless you have a reason to use something else. This would be:

```
%no running code, just a formula
d(t)=sqrt((f1(t)-v1)^2+(f2(t)-v2)^2+(f3(t)-v3)^2)
```

Now having d defined, you want to minimize it. There are basically two approaches. If you are looking for the closest row in your data, calculate d(t) for each row and take the minimum. Another approach would be to interpolate `f1` to `f3` so you could fill the gaps between your rows, then again search for the minimum `d(t)`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But let's make it more simple if I have just f1(t), not f2 and not f3(t). then how is it possible to find the range of time for f1(t) values?

Comment: Then you would calculate `abs(f1(t)-v1)`, for a match it is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, to find position of data in column#2:

```
data            = xlsread('Q1.xlsx');
ref             = 0.7636;               % your reference value
lb              = data(:,2) <  ref;     % find lower value
ub              = data(:,2) >  ref;     % find greater value
lower_bound     = find(data(:,2)==max(data(lb,2))); % find lower value position
upper_bound     = find(data(:,2)==min(data(ub,2))); % find greater value position
row             = data(sort([lower_bound upper_bound]),1);  % find position in column#1
```

and result will be `row = [6960;7020]`.